# mongodb behavior when mongo server is stopped

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I used Mongo with mongodb.MongoClient like this

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort));
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
  if (!mongoClient) {
      logger.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
      process.exit(1);
  }
  var dbName = config['mongo.db'];
  var db = mongoClient.db(dbName);
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db);
});
```

The above code works fine.

- Now on command line I stopped mongo.
- if I do any operation like `collectionDriver.save`, I get no error callback.

collectionDriver.save is defined as

```
//save new object
CollectionDriver.prototype.save = function(collectionName, obj, callback) {
    this.getCollection(collectionName, function(error, the_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        obj.created_at = new Date();
        the_collection.insert(obj, function(error, result) {
          if (error) callback(error)
          else callback(null, result);
        });
      }
    });
};
```

If I start mongodb again, it works as expected.

What is the expected behavior of `CollectionDriver.prototype.save` when I shutdown mongo server?

Comment: @zangw The normal behaviour of course is to wait for a connection until the timeout Seems rational does it not? It would not be rational to just start producing errors. It really doesn't matter what your "opinion" is, but what the driver does and what the current settings are.

Answer (score 1):

I had partial understanding. After following thru

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/connection_failures/

I found if I set `bufferMaxEntries : 0`, I start getting errors as expected.

By default mongodb buffers operartions.